# Take data from a table to display as plain text

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

I want to take data from each row to display as simple text on the same page in a paragraph.

Example table below:

```
<table>
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th class="a header">A</th>
            <th class="b header">B</th>
            <th class="c header">C</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td class="a">A1</td>
            <td class="b">B1</td>
            <td class="c">C1</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td class="a">A2</td>
            <td class="b">B2</td>
            <td class="c">C2</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

The output should look like:

```
A1 B1 C1   A2 B2 C2
```

I have tried look for the solution, but it is not working. I appreciate any help in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `document.querySelectorAll('td')` to get all the `td` elements. Iterate over the elements using forEach loop and get their text using `textContent`. In the `paragraph` add this text using `innerHTML`

```js
document.querySelector('#a').querySelectorAll('td').forEach((e)=>document.querySelector('#here').innerHTML+=e.textContent + " ")
```

```html
<table id="a">
     <thead>
      <tr>
       <th class="a header">A</th>
       <th class="b header">B</th>
       <th class="c header">C</th>
      </tr>
     </thead>
     <tbody>
      <tr>
       <td class="a">A1</td>
       <td class="b">B1</td>
       <td class="c">C1</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
       <td class="a">A2</td>
       <td class="b">B2</td>
       <td class="c">C2</td>
      </tr>
     </tbody>
   </table>
   
   <p id="here"></p>
```

Using jquery, get all the `td` elements and iterate over them using `each` and append the `text` to the `paragraph` using `append()`

```js
$('#a').find('td').each(function(i,e){
$('#here').append($(e).text() + " ")
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table id="a">
     <thead>
      <tr>
       <th class="a header">A</th>
       <th class="b header">B</th>
       <th class="c header">C</th>
      </tr>
     </thead>
     <tbody>
      <tr>
       <td class="a">A1</td>
       <td class="b">B1</td>
       <td class="c">C1</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
       <td class="a">A2</td>
       <td class="b">B2</td>
       <td class="c">C2</td>
      </tr>
     </tbody>
   </table>
   
   <p id="here"></p>
```

Comment: Now, if I have more than one table each with its own id, how do I target only one table?

Comment: Adding #tableid in this line does not work document.querySelectorAll('#tableid > td').forEach((e)=>document.querySelector('#here').innerHTML+=e.textContent + " ")

Comment: `document.querySelectorAll('#tableid > td` This won't work here. Instead use `document.querySelectorAll('#tableid).querySelector('td')`

Comment: all your answers are perfect, thanks. Now I am trying to take the same line of thought to work with a table created on wpdatatables (wordpress plugin) and its not working. Any idea?

Answer (score 0):

Try like this, using HTML DOM children Property

```js
var dataTable = document.getElementsByTagName('table');
var dataTableBody = dataTable[0].children[1];
for (var i = 0; i < dataTableBody.length; i++) {
  console.log(dataTableBody[i].innerHTML)
}
```

```html
<table>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th class="a header">A</th>
      <th class="b header">B</th>
      <th class="c header">C</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td class="a">A1</td>
      <td class="b">B1</td>
      <td class="c">C1</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td class="a">A2</td>
      <td class="b">B2</td>
      <td class="c">C2</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: how to output as paragraph?

Comment: replace console.log(dataTableBody[i].innerHTML) with '<p>'+dataTableBody[i].innerHTML+'<p>' or if you using es6, try with template literal `<p>${dataTableBody[i].innerHTML}<p>`